# How can I embed extra column/external URLs in Flask-appbuilder list/detail model view?

Tags: flask-appbuilder

Flask-appbuilder's ModelView can display list and detail for a model. Very handy and save many times for CURD operations.

Sometimes the application demands more features with extra column(s) besides CURD operations. For example, in a IoT related Device ModelView, besides CRUD, I want to link to anther realtime gauge web page, or call Web API offered by device server to send command to device.

In other Python framework, like Tornado/Cyclone, I will manually designed a template page (with extra buttons) and (embed extra) javascript code. But I am still not familiar with FAB's structure.

I can make these extra operations as external links to other exposed methods.  And add these links to models as data fields. But I think these design is quite ugly. And its URL is too long to display as well.

Any better ideas? Which methods should be overriden?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from FAB's issues site on [Github](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/issues/28). In models.py, you can define a method, then use the method in views.py. Then the resource list page will treat the method as addtional column. This solution has a drawback, you have to write HTML in a model method.

Here is my code.

**models.py**

```
class Device(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    snr = Column(String(256), unique = True)
    name = Column(String(128))
    addr = Column(String(256))
    latitude = Column(Float)
    longitude = Column(Float)
    status = Column(Enum('init','normal','transfer','suspend'), default = 'init')
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('account.id'))    
    owner = relationship("Account")

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_gauge_url(self):
        btn = "<a href=\"/gaugeview/{}\" class=\"btn btn-social-icon\"><i class=\"fa fa-dashboard\"></a>".format(self.id)
        return btn
```

**views.py**

```
class DeviceView(ModelView):        
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Device)
    related_views = [PermitView, EventView]

    label_columns = {'snr':'SNR', 
        'owner_id':'Owner',
        'get_gauge_url':'Gauge'}
    list_columns = ['name','snr','addr','owner','get_gauge_url']
    edit_columns = ['name','snr','owner','addr','latitude','longitude','status',]
    add_columns = edit_columns

    show_fieldsets = [
        ('Summary',
            {'fields':['name','snr','owner']}
        ),
        ('Device Info',
            {'fields':['addr','latitude','longitude','status'],'expanded':True}
        ),
    ]
```